# How to get a HTML submit button in an ASP.NET page to call a controller method in MVC controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC web application and I want to get a HTML submit button in one webpage to access a post controller method in my controller class, and finally link to another page on the site such as Profile.aspx through this controller method. My current situation is as follows:

I have a HTML webpage that is my index view as follows:

```
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    Username<br/>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Password<br/>
    <input id="Password1" type="password" /><br />
    <br />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Login" /><br />
</div>
```

When I hit the login button I want to link to a LogIn() method in my controller class and subsequently redirect to a page, my LogIn controller looks like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn()
{
    return View();
}
```

How do I access this method of the controller through the button and how do I redirect to another page?

All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Where is your form tag?

Comment: Hi Jenny,
My webpage currently does not contain a form tag, it's just html wrapped in asp:content tags

Comment: You need a form tag. It defines the URL where the data of your form is sent to.

Comment: You can't put <form> tags in an asp.net webforms page if the master page already has a <form runat="server"> that wraps everything, as is the norm for webforms projects.

Comment: You are right. But Matt's page is not ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your  tag, give the URL to your controller/action to `action` attribute and put your HTML in your form.

```
<form action='@Url.Action("LogIn","ControllerName")' method="post" >
<h1>Login</h1>
Username
<br />
<input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
<br />
Password
<br />
<input id="Password1" type="password" /><br />
<br />
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Login" /><br />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Correct. Also make sure that you use label tags to specify your labels.

Comment: Hi Umair,
This is not working for me, I passed my controllername instead of the "ControllerName" field you specified but my webpage does not redirect when I use a RedirectToAction("www.google.com") in my controller method

Comment: `@Url.Action("LogIn", "ControllerName")` is the razor syntax.
If you are using the regular ASP.NET syntax it should be `<%= Url.Action("LogIn", "ControllerName") %>`

Comment: `RedirectToAction("www.google.com")` won't work because `www.google.com` is not an action in your application. Instead use, `return Redirect("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: Hi LazyTarget,
Does the first line look like : 

<%'Url.Action("LogIn","ControllerName")' method="post" %> or does the form action tag still wrap it?

Comment: @MattMcGrath Like so: `<form action='<%= Url.Action("LogIn","ControllerName") %>' method="post"></form>`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Html.BeginForm`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogIn", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <h1>Login</h1>
    Username<br/>
    <input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" /><br />
    <br />
    Password<br/>
    <input id="Password1" name="Password1" type="password" /><br />
    <br />
    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Login" /><br />
}
```

And Changes you controller as

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(string Text1, string Password1)
{
    // Login logic
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap the login controls within a `<form>` tag, and specifying a action attribute.

Ex:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("LogIn","ControllerName")' method="post">
    <!-- Login controls -->
</form>
```

By doing this when the form is submitted (pressing on a button with `type="submit"` or pressing enter in a textbox) this is routed to the `LogIn()` method in the specified controller.

If you want to post data, like the username and password then you have to set the `name` attribute on the input controls.

Ex.

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" name="username" />
```

That makes it possible to receive the value of the text box inside the action method. The only thing you have to do is to update the action method to begin using the data.

Ex.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogIn(string username, string password)
{
    // Login logic
    return View();
}
```